# UISearchBar, how can i keep dimming view(shadow background) always show

Tags: uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

when i use UISearchBar => press the bar => show the search mode with dimming view , but when input some search text , dimming view disapper . how can i keep dimming view always show

thank u!

Comment: did that start happening on ios7?